# Schedule BigQuery backfill programmatically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need to schedule the backfill in transfer service for at least a few 100 times for several data sources.

The [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/scheduleRuns) is deprecated and the [python client](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquerydatatransfer/latest/gapic/v1/types.html) is not helping either.

How can I automate this?

Comment: startManualRuns can't solve your use case?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/create, you should be able to create a transfer and setting "schedule" and "scheduleOptions" in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs#TransferConfig

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i am looking into it. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @YunZhang isn't it for creating the data transfer at the beginning and a one off backfill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Yun Zhang is right. I will elaborate more on this.

The [deprecated method](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/scheduleRuns) required you to setup transfers in a specific schedule. The creation of regular ones was different and used another endpoint.

Now, by using the [*ScheduledOptions*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs#TransferConfig) argument, we can set times for the transfers to start. We are able to now schedule (or not) the transfers. This is why using that endpoint is the right path.

Hope this is helpful! :)